# Problem With OpenCVSharp and Gaussian Blur

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

This function should blur any image given to it.
I'm trying to return a bitmap as the output of this function but for some reason, it never returns a value no matter how much I wait.
Edit: I'm aware there are better/much more efficient ways to convert bitmap into mat and vise versa for now..that is not what I'm trying to fix

```
public Bitmap GussianBlurr(Bitmap OriginalImage)
{
    //gussian blurr the picture and returns it
    Bitmap GussianBlurrImage = new Bitmap(OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height);
    //saves the original image into a temp image
    OriginalImage.Save("temp.PNG");

    //applies gussian blurr using opencvsharp
    Mat img = Cv2.ImRead("temp.PNG");
    Mat dst = new Mat();
    Cv2.GaussianBlur(img, dst, new OpenCvSharp.Size(5, 5), 0);

    File.Delete("temp.PNG");

    //saves the image
    dst.SaveImage("temp.PNG");

    //saves intoBitmap
    GussianBlurrImage = new Bitmap("temp.PNG");
    File.Delete("temp.PNG");
    return GussianBlurrImage;
}
```

Comment: `"it never returns a value no matter how much I wait"` Have you tried to debug this function with a breakpoint? Does it hit your breakpoint? In which line does it freezes?